# Pedal axle measurement?

Tags: mountain-bike, pedals

Could somebody please tell me what the numbers 19 and 12 mean that are stamped on my pedal axles?

I’m looking to buy new upgraded pedals for my new Scott aspect 940 but need to know the right diameter.

I hear a lot about 9/16 inch and half-inch, so are those numbers 19 and 12 telling me the exact diameter?

As you can tell I’m a bit of a novice any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly is it stamped? How exactly does it look like? I do not think it is the size.  You will have the standard common size almost for sure. A picture would help.

Comment: Just joined this site not sure how to add pics il try n work it out but the numbers are on the end of the pedal thread so when the pedal is fully fitted they are visible on the inside of the crank on the end of the pedal shaft 19 is stamped as a bigger number with the number 12 in smaller text Thanks

Comment: The pedals are VP VP-536 if that helps and the bike is a 2020 Scott Aspect 940 Medium frame Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have the normal standard omnipresent pedal type with a 9/16 inch thread. If the size is not specifically indicated, it almost certainly fits. You canfirm it by some crude measurement.

The manufacturer speaks about a 7 mm boron steel axle, but that is hidden inside, it is not the thread diameter.

The number on your pedal might be a date of manufacture or some batch number.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I think it will be the standard 9/16 I’m gonna ring a Scott dealer  tomorrow just to be sure Thanks again